# How to make SplashScreen show up via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a game I am making, and I want to create a splash screen that shows up for 3 seconds before the game starts. However, I am unable to accomplish this because I don't know how to make the splash screen show up successfully, also WITHOUT the game starting to run in the background. (The parades start to move as soon as the game loads)

It's a Mardi Gras game, and there's a parade in the back. I want the splash screen to show up (just a white splash screen with the words "Mardi Gras Parade!" appearing) for 3 seconds, then disappear, and the game starts.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jfiddleperson/q0f7cr9L/5/) (which unfortunately does not show the parades moving because I can't attach files to the JSFiddle, sorry).

But here is my [repo](https://github.com/wangjess/mardigrasgame), if you want to clone it and open it up in your browser to see the full animations.

Basically, the Splash Screen should cover the entire left portion of the game (with the grey road) with a white background. It shouldn't cover the right yellow side that has the scoreboard information. I am trying to achieve this using Jquery, but I am unable to do this. I don't think my Jquery actually works, as there are no animations, and I can still see the game background. I got the very simple code from this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36561936/show-splash-screen-when-page-loads-but-at-least-for-x-seconds/36562003).

This is my Jquery code that controls the Splash Screen:

```js
function splash(param) {
  var time = param;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#splash').hide();
  }, time);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onload="splash(3000)">

  <div class='outer-container'>

    <div class='game-window'>
      <div id="splash">
        <div id="splash-content">Mardi Gras Parade!!!!!!</div>
      </div>
      <div id="actualGame">

        <div id='player' class='playerObject'>
          <img class='player-avatar' src='img/person.png' height='50px' />
          <!--person img: src='https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fclipart-library.com%2Fnew_gallery%2F54-540691_others-clipart-helpful-person-generic-person.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fclipart-library.com%2Fclip-art%2F54-540691_others-clipart-helpful-person-generic-person.htm&tbnid=V19QgOYn0jYyzM&vet=12ahUKEwidx5GevcrnAhUJ0KwKHQynD9AQMygBegUIARCJAg..i&docid=hVn27RN51ga3yM&w=920&h=830&q=person&hl=en&ved=2ahUKEwidx5GevcrnAhUJ0KwKHQynD9AQMygBegUIARCJAg'-->
        </div>
        <div id="paradeRoute">
          <div id="dottedLine"></div>
          <div id="paradeFloats" class="bothFloats">
            <div id="paradeFloat1" class='paradeFloat'>
              <img src='img/parade_float_1.gif' height='80px' />
              <!-- src: https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.clipart.email%2Fb0a85a880dc856c8129f51d506469510_mardi-gras-background-transparent-png-clipart-free-download-ywd_474-256.gif&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.clipart.email%2Fclipart%2Ftransparent-background-mardi-gras-float-clipart-231098.html&tbnid=QDcU0K_06jcQJM&vet=12ahUKEwj40aPwwsrnAhUFgK0KHU4qCkQQMygEegUIARDsAQ..i&docid=7_c8q7QtWx89bM&w=474&h=256&q=mardi%20gras%20parade%20clip%20art&hl=en&client=firefox-b-1-e&ved=2ahUKEwj40aPwwsrnAhUFgK0KHU4qCkQQMygEegUIARDsAQ -->
            </div>
            <div id="paradeFloat2" class='paradeFloat'>
              <img src='img/parade_float_2.png' height='80px' />
              <!-- Adapted from src: https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.clipart.email%2F2075f16e1c812d5ba8ecece2b6924d75_mardi-gras-clipart-at-getdrawingscom-free-for-personal-use-_340-270.jpeg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.clipart.email%2Fclipart%2Fmardi-gras-float-clip-art-228088.html&tbnid=_LNqQJQgyaHKcM&vet=12ahUKEwj40aPwwsrnAhUFgK0KHU4qCkQQMygLegUIARD7AQ..i&docid=Fv4gfo44aw_StM&w=340&h=270&q=mardi%20gras%20parade%20clip%20art&hl=en&client=firefox-b-1-e&ved=2ahUKEwj40aPwwsrnAhUFgK0KHU4qCkQQMygLegUIARD7AQ -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Scoreboard -->
    <div class='status-window' style='text-align: center'>
      <h3>Welcome!</h3>
      <hr>
      <br>
      <p>Score:</p>
      <h1 id='score-box'>0</h1>
      <br/>
      <div>
        <b># of beads collected:</b>
        <span id="beadsCounter">0</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <b># of candy pieces collected:</b>
        <span id="candyCounter">0</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove `onload="splash(3000)"` from `<body>`

Create a separate js file and move javascript to end of `</body>`

```html
    ...
    <script async src="scripts/index.js"></script>
  </body>
```

## Script

`scripts/index.js`

```js
function splash(time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $("#splash").hide();
      resolve();
    }, time);
  });
}

function loop() {
  $("#paradeFloats").css({ left: -300 });
  $("#paradeFloats").animate(
    {
      left: "+=850"
    },
    10000,
    "linear",
    function() {
      loop();
    }
  );
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Wait for splash to resolve after 3 seconds, Then call loop()
  splash(3000).then(() => {
    loop();
  });
});
```

Read more on [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) - Also check out the example section.

## CSS

Make the following changes to your CSS, Modify if necessary.

```css
#outer-container {
  ...
  overflow: hidden; // Hide everything outside of #outer-container
}

#splash {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#splash-content {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

## Codesandbox Example

https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-dream-8c4r9